# Instantiate class from a .cls saved in disk

Tags: vba, excel, code-reuse

I have 2 distinct VBA projects that make use of 8 identical classes. 
If i export those classes to a directory in my disk, is there a way to instantiate them programatically to avoid code duplication?

I don't see any problem by having the same code in 2 distinct projects, but my boss asked if it is possible and so far i haven't found anything that could lead me to an answer in the microsoft online help and in some books i've got.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. What do you mean "if you export those classes to a directory in my disk, is there a way to instantiate them to avoid code duplication?" And why do you have 8 identical classes?

Comment: @BenBlack I think he means he has 8 classes that are used in two different projects. Currently he has copied the classes between the two.

Comment: What I would suggest is have a 3rd project that is your class 'library'. You can set a reference to it in each of your main projects and then have access to all the classes in each. You will need factory methods in a standard module of your library to create the class instances (or parent depending on your object model) as they can only be "Public Not Creatable". However, once instantiated they can be used fully. Alternatively, and more simply if you don't think the classes will change that much, try and explain to your boss why it is simpler all round to not do this.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense now. Your suggestion of a common library that can be referenced from both is the best way to go about it then.

Comment: Cor_Blimey, are you suggesting that the common classes be stored in a separate workbook that's loaded by the macros in each project? I think that might be a good approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround I exported the methods in those classes to a DLL file and saved it in the server. Whenever the user opens the .xlsm file, a method is called to register the DLL in their computers and then I can use the methods and properties contained in it without further problems.

I also considered the other answers to this question. But sending 2 files (one that contains the datasheet that will be used and another one for the library) would not be a good idea (users would not understand what is the reason for that) because those programs will be used by a lot of users.

Answer (score 3):

Now that I understand your question, a central library of sorts may be your best option, there are others but I'm always a fan of libraries.

To achieve this:

- Create a new workbook, import all of your class modules in to the VBA project in that workbook. Name your project something like MyCentralLibrary (something different than VBAProject)
- Set the class module's Instancing Property to PublicNotCreatable
  (change this in the properties window)
- Now here comes the slightly
  stupid part (I never was a fan of VBA). Projects referencing this
  library will be able to see all the classes but never instantiate a
  new instance of them. So what you'll have to do is for each class you put in the library,
  write a function with the class as the return type, like so:

  ```
  Public Function GetMyClass() As MyClass
      Set GetMyClass = New MyClass
  End Function
  ```
- Now in the project you want to reference your central library. Go to Tools -> References and choose your library name from the list. Now you can instantiate classes from that library in your project like so:

  ```
  Public c As MyCentralLibrary.MyClass
  Set c = MyCentralLibrary.GetMyClass()
  ```

Again, there's other ways of doing it, but I'm always a proponent of libraries (at least in other languages)

*As a note, if/when you move between computers,, you'll obviously have to move the workbook with your library in it around and re-do the references for any projects referencing the library on the new computer.*

*My two cents, if this were to scale more I'd go ahead and grab the free version of Visual Studio and turn this into a class library that can be referenced from Excel. But that's just me and my dislike of VBA shining through ;).*

Comment: I'm not really following how you're creating a new VBA project without creating an associated workbook. Are you using Visual Studio or some other IDE other than Excel?

Comment: Ah well yes, the new project would have to be in a new workbook. It has been awhile since I used VBA, these things fade away after time I suppose. I'll edit my post.

Comment: I'm guessing if you want to use the macros on a new computer, you'll have to open the library workbook first so that the classes can be registered with COM.

Comment: Good question, I'd test it out if I had multiple computers to try it on, but I'm assuming yes. I'll also add that as a note to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, but you have to change some security settings. I do something similar to this in all my VBA projects so I can use source control.

The code to import a class module into your project would be

```
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "C:\path\to\myclass.cls"
```

In order for this to work, you have to change your security settings to allow access to the VBA project object model. This is because in the past some viruses has spread via this mechanism. The setting is in File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings... > Macro Settings > Trust access to the VBA project object model.

Comment: One thing to note with this.  If you attempt to import a class that already exists in the current code project it will not overwrite the class, but create a new one and append a number to the end of the name.  You can use the same VBComponents object to remove the existing class, just be sure to do it prior to the import.

Comment: That's a good callout. You need to call .VBComponents.Remove "NameOfClass" if the class already exists.